# How to intuit a necessary optimality conidtion involving growth rate of Lagrange multiplier in Ramsey growth model?

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth

I encountered a necessary optimality conidtion involving growth rate of Lagrange multiplier in [this note](http://www.econ2.jhu.edu/people/ccarroll/Public/LectureNotes/Growth/HamiltonianVSDiscrete/) on Ramsey model

$$\frac{\dot \lambda}{\lambda} = \mathcal {v} - (f^\prime(k)-\delta-\xi)$$

in which $\mathcal {v}$    is the time preference rate, $\xi$   is the population growth rate, and $\delta$   is the depreciation rate.

Is there some way to make sense of it in a similar fashion as Euler equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiplier is equal to marginal utility of consumption. In case of CRRA utility (i.e. $\lambda_t = c_t^{-\gamma}$), its rate of growth is then related to consumption growth:

$$
\frac{\dot \lambda}{\lambda} = \frac{\mathrm{d} \log \lambda}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{\mathrm{d} (-\gamma \log c)}{\mathrm{d} t} =  -\gamma \frac{\dot c}{c}
$$

The condition can be then rewritten as

$$
\frac{\dot c}{c} = \frac{1}{\gamma} \left[ (f'(k) - \delta - \xi) - \nu\right],
$$
so that the consumption growth rate is proportional to return on capital (less rate of time preference), which is pretty much the same as Euler equation in discrete time.